# Node.js "Error: Can not find module"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am doing the node.js lesson from lynda.com and am unable to find what is causing the "Error: Can not find module". From everything I can tell the package.json has the flight module in it.

Everything has been working so far so I know node.js is installed and running correctly. The way I am running this file is by typing "node app.js" at the command line. Also all of the files are in the same folder.

**Here is the console log:**

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\flight>node app.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './flight'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\flight\app.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\flight>
```

**Here is the code.**

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "flight",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a module for keeping track of a flight",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "JBaxter",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**index.js file**

```
 var number, origin, destination;

 exports.setNumber = function (num){
    number = num;
 };

 exports.setOrigin = function (o){
    origin = o;
 };

 exports.setDestination = function (d){
    destination = d;
 };

 exports.getInfo = function() {
    return {
        number: number,
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination
    };
 };
```

**app.js file**

```
var flight = require('./flight');

flight.setOrgin('LAX');
flight.setDestination('DCA');
flight.setNumber(462);

console.log(flight.getInfo());
```

Any help with be great. I thought the name within the package.json file was your module but maybe I am incorrect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please show your folder structure?

Comment: Change ``require('./flight')`` to ``require('./index');``

Comment: Path `./flight'` points to `C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\flight\flight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"./flight" does not evaluate to index.js in your case.

If you create a subdir :

```
flight
  - index.js
```

then you can require("./flight") and have it evaluated to "./flight/index.js".

In your case, simplest thing you could to do :

```
require("./index.js");
```

Comment: There is an issue with the lesson. A subdir needs to be created then I can use require("./flight"). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the following way:

```
var flight = require('./index.js');
```

OR

```
var flight = require('./index');
```

Following code will not work because the node will look for module named 'flight' in node_modules folder

```
var flight = require('flight');
```